# Elastic search application side join - pagination and aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination

I have many-to-many relationship in db. when records are indexed into Elastic search will be using [application side join](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/application-joins.html). given joining two resultsets from Elasticsearch will have to be merged at an application level - will be losing out of the box pagination that Elastic search offers (on merged results sets at application side) and also most importantly [aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html). trying to find out way to go about leveraging ES aggregations and pagination while using application side join and merging results on application side?

Comment: You could always create a temporary index with the results of both your queries, after the application-side join; just loop through the paginated results, and bulk index each "page", for each resultset. Then you could do aggregations on it easily.

Comment: @SloanAhrens : that's an interesting idea. wondering about a few things with that idea. first is response time to the user when application will be first 1)joining results from first two queries 2) index new data set into a "temporary" index and then get all the records from temporary index and then clear "temporary" index to have a clean slate for the next query run? wondering if this will be too resource intensive? where app will have to first index merged data into "temporary" index and then read data from it and then delete all of that data?

Comment: Yeah, it's probably not something you can do in real-time. Unless you have really patient users. Or lots of servers. ;)